How to estimate stack usage of a function including all nested calls?
I'm working on embedded projects for Cortex-M microcontrollers and need to estimate the total stack usage of a function, including all the functions it calls (directly or indirectly).
I'm using GCC with the -fstack-usage option, which provides the stack usage for individual functions. However, it doesn't account for nested calls. To calculate the total stack usage, I thought about combining this data with a callgraph.
I tried generating a callgraph using cflow with preprocessing enabled and proper include paths, but:

It produces many errors (likely due to static functions with the same name, static inline functions, or GCC-specific attributes).
The output file is massive (hundreds of MB), suggesting it misinterpreted the code.

I noticed GCC has options like:

-fdump-analyzer-callgraph (produces a Graphviz file, but the format/documentation is unclear).
-fcallgraph-info (not sure how to use it).
-fdump-tree (not sure how to use it).

Questions:

How can I reliably generate a callgraph for my code using GCC or other tools?
Does anyone have experience with -fdump-analyzer-callgraph, -fdump-tree or -fcallgraph-info and can explain how to leverage them?
Are there better open-source tools (maybe in the toolchain) or approaches for calculating stack usage across nested function calls?

I found some other post on this argument such as How to determine maximum stack usage in embedded system with gcc? or How to determine maximum stack usage in embedded system? but I am not sure if they can help me and how.
Any advice or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!
